# Relative links not working in HTML (Apache2)?

Tags: html, linux, apache

I'm running an Apache 2 server from my raspberry pi, and everything works fine. I wanted to configure ".htaccess", so I had to move some files around. So in "/var/www", I created a file called "html" and moved all my pictures, and webpages into it. However, I left "index.html" out inside of "/var/www." All of this works fine, except for one thing. I have a link going from index.html to another page called test.html. I have another link from test.html to go back to the index.html page, and this doesn't work. "test.html" is stored in: "/var/www/html" and "index.html" is stored in "/var/www." So, I used a relative link inside of "test.html", to go one directory up, to "/var/www/index.html", but it's not working! I keep getting this error on my browser:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /html/index.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at myIP Port 80
```

Here is the little code I used for the relative path, pretty sure it is correct.

```
<a href = "../index.html">Click here to go back</a>
```

Comment: Agh I feel stupid. I just had to clear my browser's cache and cookies for it to work!